# __init__( ) missing 1 requirement positional argument

Tags: python, class, init

I would like to ask a question related to Python 'class', because I got stuck on this example while I was practicing exercise 9.8 on this site:
https://ehmatthes.github.io/pcc_2e/solutions/chapter_9/#9-9-battery-upgrade

**Example**: *Write a separate Privileges class. The class should have one attribute, privileges, that stores a list of strings as described in Exercise 9-7. Move the show_privileges() method to this class. Make a Privileges instance as an attribute in the Admin class. Create a new instance of Admin and use your method to show its privileges.*

```
#Seperate Privileges Class from Admin Class
#This is parent class
class User:
    def __init__(person, first_name, last_name, age, location, mail):
        person.first_name = first_name
        person.last_name = last_name
        person.age = age
        person.location = location
        person.mail = mail
        person.login_attempts = 0
    def describe_user(person):
        print(f"User full name: {person.first_name} {person.last_name}")
        print(f"User age: {person.age}")
        print(f"User location: {person.location}")
        print(f"User mail: {person.mail}")
    def greet_user(person):
        print(f"Hello {person.first_name} {person.last_name}!")
    def increment_login_attempts(person):
        person.login_attempts += 1
        
    def reset_login_attempts(person):
        person.login_attempts = 0
        
#This is child class Admin
class Admin(User):
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, age, location, mail): 
        super().__init__(first_name, last_name, age, location, mail)
        '''Initialize an empty set of privileges'''
        self.privileges = Privileges()    
#Seperate Privileges class: 
class Privileges:
    def __init__(self, privilege): (1)
        self.privileges = [] (2)
        
    def show_privileges(self):
        print("\nAdministrator's privileges are:")
        for privilege in self.privileges:
            print(f"- {privilege}")
    
Tom = Admin('Tom', 'Felton', 23, "the UK", 'tomfelton@hotmail.com')
Tom.describe_user()
Tom.privileges.privileges = ["can add post", "can delete post", "can ban user", "can do bla bla"]
Tom.privileges.show_privileges()
```

After executing the whole code above I got this error:
[image]

I've checked the answer from the same site above , however I felt difficult to understand why I should change line (1) and line (2) of my code to this one:

```
def __init__(self, privileges=[]): (1)
        self.privileges = privileges  (2)
```

Comment: `def __init__(self, privilege)` declares that the class requires one argument during instantiation: `privilege`. If you don’t pass that argument, you get an error. Adding `=[]` gives it a default value and makes the argument optional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer given on the site is wrong.

If you want an optional list of privileges, you need a default parameter value. Note that because `[]` is a mutable value, you need to use something like `None` and replace it with a new empty list inside the function.

```
class Privileges:
    def __init__(self, privileges=None):
        self.privileges = [] if privileges is None else privileges
```

Using a default value of `[]` in the signature means that every instance of `Privileges` created using the default value will share the *same* list of privileges: changes to one instance's privileges will be visible in the others.